# Holomorphic function over a real interval has an extension to a subset of the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorph

In Lie algebras, and representations an elementary introduction by Hall B. it is mentioned that: "$\exp(\log(z))=z$ for $z\in (0,2)$ ($z$ real) and since both sides of this identity are holomorphic in $z$, the identity continues to hold on the whole set $\left\{|z-1|<1\right\}$."

From what I see, the argument is as follows

If $f(x)=0$ for $x\in (-R,R)$ with $f(x)$ holomorphic then $f(z)=0$ for $z\in \left\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<R\right\}$?

Why can this function be extended to a complex variable? is it part of some theorem?

Comment: Holomorphic extensions, if they exist are unique. Now, the zero function on any open set in $\Bbb{C}$ obviously has an extension (namely the zero function defined on all of $\Bbb{C}$). For the case of $\exp$ and $\log$, we have that $\log$ (with say the principal branch) is defined and holomorphic on $U=\Bbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0]$, and $\exp:\Bbb{C}\to\Bbb{C}$ is holomorphic, so $\exp\circ \log$ is holomorphic on $U$. In general, proving extensions exist is tricky, but here you have easy explicitly defined functions.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. From what I understand, if $f(z):E\to \mathbb{C}$ has an holomorphic extension $F(z):D\to \mathbb{C}$ with $E\subset D$, i.e. $F(z)=f(z)$ for all $z\in E$. If $E=\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}:|x-1|<1\right\}$ and $D=\left\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z-1|<1\right\}$. If $f(z)=0$ for all $z\in E$. Why $F(z)=0$ for all $z\in D$?

Comment: Look up the identity theorem (uniqueness of analytic continuation)